# Issue with UIScrollView within UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` in my storyboard that scrolls vertically. Inside of this scrollView, I have programmatically created a horizontal `UIScrollView`.

The vertical scrollView is called scroller. The horizontal UIScrollView is called scrollInfo. For some reason i am unable to register when the horizontal scrollInfo is being used. Any ideas on why this isn't working?

This is in my viewDidLoad:

```
scrollInfo = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 
155,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/4)];
//This will create a scrollview of device screen frame

scrollInfo.scrollEnabled = YES;

NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, 
    self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/4)];
    awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 
    alpha:1];
    [scrollInfo addSubview:awesomeView];
}

// 3 views added horizontally to the UIScrollView by using xOrigin.

scrollInfo.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, 
self.view.frame.size.height/4);

[scroller addSubview:scrollInfo];
//Add scrollview to viewcontroller

scrollInfo.pagingEnabled = YES;

pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init]; //SET a property of UIPageControl
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,200,self.view.frame.size.width, 
self.view.frame.size.height/8);
pageControl.numberOfPages = 3; //as we added 3 diff views
pageControl.currentPage = 0;
[scroller addSubview:pageControl];
```

Here is my `scrollViewDidScroll` method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if ([mainTableView isEqual: scrollView]) {

        if (mainTableView.contentOffset.y > 0) {
            // yourTableView is not on top.
            NSLog(@"not top");
        }

        else {
            // yourTableView is already on top.
            NSLog(@"is top");
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0 
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
                scroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
            } completion:NULL];
        }
    }

    else {

        CGFloat pageWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((scrollInfo.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2 ) / pageWidth) + 
        1; //this provide you the page number
        pageControl.currentPage = page;// this displays the white dot as current page
        NSLog(@"page");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forget to connect `UIScrollViewDelegate` to your scrollviews. After doing this you better operate with scrollview.tag to recognize which scrollview calling delegate